# undefined javascript value after echoing a function's parameters in html onload tag php

Tags: javascript, php, null, echo, undefined

I've got a php function which echos out a skill-bar object's tags to render it to the screen and I'm trying to pass in a function to define it's individual percentage that it should be when it loads, but for some reason the value that defines the percentage is undefined when I debug it in the console even though it called the function perfectly fine:

```
rotating circle undefined%
```

Here's where I'm declaring the function to set the percentage in a functions.php file (simplified to show exactly where the problem is, data-progress is it's starting value, it needs to be changed cause it's not very readable):

```
function echo_skillbar($data_progress, $function){
    echo " <div class='radial-progress' data-progress='$data_progress' onLoad = '$function'> " 
}
```

I call it in the main page like this:

```
<div class = "col-xs-3">
    <?php echo_skillbar(0, 'rotate_circle(80)') ?>
    <br><div class = ""><b><p>HTML</p></b></div>
</div>
```

And here's the javascript function, so I change the data-progress attribute from it's starting point (0) to 80(%), but that value is coming up as undefined even though I passed it in and the function loads fine, makes no sense:

```
function rotate_circle(value){

    console.log("rotating circle " + value + "%");

    $('head style[type="text/css"]').attr('type', 'text/less');
    less.refreshStyles();

    window.animate = function () {
        $('.radial-progress').attr('data-progress', value);
    }

    setTimeout(window.animate, 2000);
    $('.radial-progress').click(window.animate);
}
```

Looking forward to any answers cause I am stumped as a tree right now

Comment: What HTML output do you get? ignore the Javascript error for a sec

Comment: It's somehow related to `onLoad` event I think. What happens in JS console when you run your function there? Try changing `onLoad` to `onClick` - was output right?

Comment: Hey onClick works! and my HTML output is:
    '<div class="radial-progress" data-progress="80" onclick="rotate_circle(40)">'
So I know it's echoing correctly:

I wonder why it's undefined onLoad then?

Comment: Have you tried with `<?php echo_skillbar(0, 'rotate_circle(&quot;80&quot;)') ?>` ?

Comment: I don't know how PHP corresponds to DOM events, but it seems that `onLoad` event was already fired when your `echo_skillbar` was echoed

Comment: Doing it that way doesn't work with onload, besides I need to pass in the integer value for it to work. It actually works with onclick, it's not quite behaving the way I anticipated but it does work at the base level. I just need it to work when the page loads.

Comment: @Ultra that is an incredibly good point you make. I hadn't thought about that. One sec. I'll look into it

Comment: Try "DOM Mutation events" - listen in JS for `div.radial-progress` appearence in DOM and when it happens execute desired function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how PHP corresponds to DOM events, but it seems that `onLoad` event was already fired when your `echo_skillbar` was echoed

Try inline JS like so:

```
function echo_skillbar($data_progress, $function){
    echo " <div class='radial-progress' data-progress='$data_progress'> ";
    echo '<script>{$function}()<script>';
}
```

That way JS function will invoke as soon as your `<div>` loads. You just need to change internals of your JS function to get right attributes.

Comment: Ok I've tested this a bit and I've had to move jQuery to the top, and it still gives me an undefined error, but changing onload to onclick works, with your point about DOM mutation events, I don't actually know what they are or about the order of which the DOM loads stuff. So I'm just gonna go off and research that stuff now. And come back here to your points and try them all. This is all really helpful stuff though man so thankyou!

Comment: Ah sorry if I wasn't clear, no it doesn't, but I'm not sure whether I'm doing it wrong or not because this is new stuff that I've never heard of before so I need to research and come back to this to make sure it's me and not your code if that makes sense? :)!

Comment: What's console output than? Could you show demo? Are you passing a parameter in php `echo` - JS funcion has one: `function rotate_circle(value)`